# Cleanup Function in useEffect using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm using React Typescript and I have the following warning:

`warning  Missing return type on function`

This is my code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', fetchAllFriends, { once: true })

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', fetchAllFriends)
    }
  }, [fetchAllFriends])
```

Does that mean that we need a `return (): void` on every cleanup function inside useEffect?

Comment: It means that your **linter** has a rule that you disagree with. As I likewise disagree with that rule, I would turn the rule off, but it is your call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the above warning is happening is probably because you have activated following ESLint rule:

```
@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
```

To answer your question, you can set the return type as `void`.

Alternatively, you can turn the above rule off, as you don't always have to explicitly set the return type of all of your methods as TypeScript can usually infer the return types based on what is returned on the method. Personally, I turn it off for most of my projects.

```
getUser() {
  return service.getUser();
}
```

For instance, with the above scenario, TypeScript should be able to infer the return type without the need the specify the return type.

---

EDIT: as mentioned by @paolostyle in the comments, if you wish to keep the rule, but disable the rule for your scenario, you can toggle the `allowExpressions` option and set it to `true`.

```
"@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": ["error", {
  "allowExpressions": true,
}]
```

Comment: Alternatively you could also add `allowExpressions: true` to that rule config. That will disable this rule for inline anonymous functions, like the cleanup function in `useEffect`. However I'm personally not a fan of this rule and I'd suggest disabling it altogether.

Comment: Ahh..! Good tip. I have never explored that option as I always turn off that rule 